# Web mapping service with GEBCO bathymetry data

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, bathymetry

Is there any open web mapping service provide map tiles with GEBCO bathymetry data. As far I know Only Google uses GEBCO bathymetry data for ocean floor model. Others uses ocean as plain blue. I need a service provider of web mapping tiles which provide sea floor with GEBCO data.

Answer (score 2):

- [ESRI ocean base map](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6348e67824504fc9a62976434bf0d8d5)
- [The European Atlas of the Seas](http://ec.europa.eu/maritimeaffairs/atlas/maritime_atlas/) has a web service based on GEBCO, among others: see [here](http://maratlas.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Maratlas/Bathymetry/MapServer).

Comment: Thanks.I am using a opencyclemaps as basemap for my app. Is anyone of these basemaps can be used as same?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for GEBCO iso-bath contour lines, I've found the following tile server useful.There zoom level isn't very high, but it might work for you depending on your application.

Here is the server I call in a Leafet.js map:
    http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/web_mercator/gebco08_contours/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x} (this is outdated)

The new version can be found here:
https://gis.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/web_mercator/gebco_2014_contours/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}

Hope this helps!